# Extract values from a dict dataset based on given keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

A ASCII text file has been loaded as dict.

How to extract the particular value from a dict dataset based on given keys?

For example: the value *0.2* can be extracted (printed), if the given keys are "*John*" and "*Fraction*".

Here is my code:

```
import csv


Name    = "Jenny"
Search = "Fraction"

dct = {}

#Open csv file
with open("./test_file.txt") as fp:
    #Open reader instance 
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    #Skip header
    next(reader)
    #Iterate through rows and update dictionaries as you go 
    for row in reader:
        dct[row[0]] = row[1:]


#---- Find data entry
for item in dct:
    if item[0] == Name :
        print(item)
        dict = {key: i for i, key in enumerate(item)}
        break

print(dct)
```

The raw ASCII text file looks like:

```
Name            Fraction    Density   Temp      Gravity
John            0.0         100.0     10.0      12.3    
David           0.1         200.0     20.0      32.1    
Mary            0.2         300.0     30.0      65.4    
Dennis          0.3         400.0     40.0      43.2    
Jenny           0.2         500.0     50.0      98.7
```

Comment: I don't really understand your find data entry loop. What is it supposed to do? Wouldn't it be enough to do `if Name in dct: print(dct[Name]) ..`? By the way, you are using `dict` as a variable in your loop, I guess that wasn't intentional.

Comment: `for item in dct:` is only going iterate through the **keys** in the dictionary — in other words each item will be (single) name the way the dictionary is constructed. Your criteria for a "match" is also unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your current strategy, the task can't be done because you aren't recording the header keys like `"Fraction"` (you explicitly skip the header). In fact, when I run your code, I get this dictionary:

```py
{'John            0.0         100.0     10.0      12.3    ': [],
 'David           0.1         200.0     20.0      32.1    ': [],
 'Mary            0.2         300.0     30.0      65.4    ': [],
 'Dennis          0.3         400.0     40.0      43.2    ': [],
 'Jenny           0.2         500.0     50.0      98.7': []}
```

Note that each key is actually a single string, composing a line of your file. this surely isn't what you wanted, and it probably happened because you tried to read a space-delimited file with `csv`, which is for parsing comma-separated files.

Fortunately, there is a simple solution for table-like data: [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

```py
>>> import pandas as pd

# Read the file, using whitespace as the delimiter between columns.
>>> df = pd.read_csv("test_file.txt", delim_whitespace=True)
>>> df
     Name  Fraction  Density  Temp  Gravity
0    John       0.0    100.0  10.0     12.3
1   David       0.1    200.0  20.0     32.1
2    Mary       0.2    300.0  30.0     65.4
3  Dennis       0.3    400.0  40.0     43.2
4   Jenny       0.2    500.0  50.0     98.7
```

Now you can find which row has John for the Name, and access the corresponding entry of the Fraction column.

```py
>>> float(df["Fraction"].loc[df["Name"] == "John"])
0.0
>>> float(df["Fraction"].loc[df["Name"] == "Jenny"])
0.2
```

If you don't want to use `pandas`, the alternative is to create a dictionary mapping names to a list of data, and also recording the header so you know which entry of the list to access.

```py
>>> with open("test_file.txt", 'r') as infile:
        # Read the file, ignore space at the front or end, and separate the text by line.
...     text = infile.read().strip().split('\n')
...
# Get the header but ignore the Name label.
>>> header = text[0].split()[1:]

# Put the rest of the file in a dictionary.
>>> rows = [row.split() for row in text[1:]]
>>> data = {row[0]: [float(r) for r in row[1:]] for row in rows}

>>> header
['Fraction', 'Density', 'Temp', 'Gravity']
>>> data
{'John': [0.0, 100.0, 10.0, 12.3],
 'David': [0.1, 200.0, 20.0, 32.1],
 'Mary': [0.2, 300.0, 30.0, 65.4],
 'Dennis': [0.3, 400.0, 40.0, 43.2],
 'Jenny': [0.2, 500.0, 50.0, 98.7]}

>>> def access_entry(name, column):
...     return data[name][header.index(column)]
...
>>> access_entry("Jenny", "Fraction")
0.2
```